# How to restrict my Facebook cover photo from copying by others?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

In Facebook i'm having a image as Cover photo. I want that photo should not be copied by others but they can view it as my cover photo. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not possible. The facebook user will always be able to click on the 'print screen' key on his computer and copy the whole desktop image to his clipboard. Then he can cut your image and store it for himself.

Comment: But in the album I restricted it to see only by me. When I set as cover photo it is available to copy by others

Comment: That's how it works, nothing you can do about it. If you don't like it, don't make it a profile photo, but upload it to another album.